# How can I run Storybook Jest Tests for an Nx library?

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs, storybook, nrwl-nx

I have an Nx monorepo with multiple Angular libraries in it, each of them has its own Storybook configuration (I set up the Storybook config according to [this Nx tutorial](https://nx.dev/storybook/overview-angular)).

Everything's been working fine, I've been able to build my Storybook for each library and build my components in isolation.

However, I wanted to add Interaction Tests as described in [this Storybook tutorial](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/ui-testing-handbook/react/en/interaction-testing/) to one of my libraries, the Inventory library.
(Basically I wanted to be able to include interaction tests for the component in each of the stories' `play` function).

The tutorial asks me to add a "test-storybook" script to my package.json though, like so:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test-storybook": "test-storybook"
  }
}
```

However, I don't understand how to complete this step in terms of an Nx Angular library...where do I include this script? What options should I pass it, so it runs the test associated to the Inventory library only?

Any help is appreciated, and further questions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have your answer already. But for someone new coming to this.
You can follow https://github.com/storybookjs/test-runner#getting-started.

You put the above script in your package.json  of your project (or anywhere you want to run scripts from) you just have to make sure that the storybook instance of the library you want to test is running on port 6006 (or you can specify a url, static or just a diff port with --url)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, didn't think I'd ever get one haha. However, this isn't working :( I added the script in my package.json file, under the scripts section. Then I ran the following command: `npx nx run test-storybook --url http://localhost:7011`. It tried to run the tests over my main app instead of over the Inventory library, so I ran it again like this: `npx nx run inventory-feature:test-storybook --url http://localhost:7011`. But it gave me the following error: `Cannot find configuration for task inventario-feature:test-storybook`.

Comment: not clear to me what you did (also the error that you mention seems specific to your project so w/o more info i cant help). The main point from the link i mention above i think you are missing is that: 1) first y run the command that launches storybook to port 6006 and 2) then run  npm run  test-storybook (or you can even deploy your storybook in a static and run against that or diff ports ) , in your case since you probably are running the command from some place that the addoncant figure out your storries you probably need to follow the Index.json mode section from the link as well